# Can I change the suffix number of file name when rendering an image sequence?

Tags: rendering

For example, when I render 20-50 frame intervals in a blender, I want the name of the output file to be numbered 10-30.

current my method to achieve that is outputting 20-50 numbered sequences
(img_20.png, img_21.png ... img_50.png) for this and then taking them to a separate file renamer application for processing.
And rename them as img_01.png, img_02.png ... img_30.png.

However, if this can be achieved through Blender's GUI or CLI, the degree of freedom of batch rendering is likely to increase.

Is it possible?

Comment: Nope. ...and TBH Doesn't make much sense to do that. The number relates to the frame of the scene so if you'd 'name' it differently you don't know what you've actually rendered -> mess of data. Just rename it after the rendering is finished as you are already doing.

Comment: Okay i see. Maybe I should find a renamer that supports the command line, or investigate how to batch process the names of files in CMD.

Comment: Many file managers support batch renaming. Just select your files, right click on one of them and click "rename". A dialog will open and ask for the name structure you want. I can confirm it works with Dolphin on Linux and Explorer on Windows, it's a standard feature these years.

Comment: @thibsert That's right. But that's still a manual operation. I want to automate.

Answer (score 0):

You only need add `#` on suffix of you save file.

Comment: This is wrong, if you add hashtags (`#`) to the file name in `Output Properties > Output > Output Path`, it only changes how many numbers are at least printed. `##.png` would result in `02.png` and `12.png`, whereas `#.png` would result in `2.png` and `12.png`, for frames 2 en 12 respectively.